# MySQL query and subquery inexpert

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 4 tables:

1. entrevista

   - id_entrevista PK
   - candidato FK candidato (#id_candidato)
   - proceso FK proceso (#id_proceso)
   - resultado
2. candidato

   - id_candidato PK
3. proceso

   - id_proceso PK
   - dpt FK DPT (#id_dpt)
4. DPT

   - id_dpt PK

I need in my query to search, for each 'DPT', show the count of 'id_entrevista' of each 'proceso' but entrevista.resultado = 1 and has to be the last row of each entrevista.candidato

But if i have more rows of same entrevista.candidato:

for only now I can take the amount (count) of entrevista.id_entrevista:

```
SELECT p.id_proceso,
    (
            SELECT count(id_entrevista)
            from entrevista
            where entrevista.proceso = p.id_proceso
        ) as total
from proceso p
where dpt = 99   //this is the current dpt
```

But I need the subquery on:

```
SELECT p.id_proceso,
        (
                SELECT count(id_entrevista)
                from entrevista
                where entrevista.proceso = p.id_proceso
            ) as total,
       (
        //here
         ) as approved
    from proceso p
    where dpt = 99   //this is the current dpt
```

I have the idea I need to check the last `entrevista` of every `candidato` in the `proceso`. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
 FROM  entrevista
 WHERE proceso = 120 and candidato = 374
 ORDER BY fecha_entrevista DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will give me `resultado` which is 1 or 0 as result. I need only `count` the rows which return 1 from the query

eg:

```
|entrevista |
 -----------
 0001 | 0001 | 0001 | 20-12-2017 | 1
 0002 | 0001 | 0001 | 21-12-2017 | 0
 0003 | 0002 | 0001 | 20-12-2017 | 1
 0004 | 0003 | 0001 | 20-12-2017 | 1

 | candidato |
 ----------
 0001 | Foo 
 0002 | Bar
 0003 | John Doe

 |proceso |
 ----------
 0001 | FooProceso | 0001

 | DPT |
 ----
 0001 | FooDPT
```

Expected output:

```
 Proceso    | Amount of interviews | Amount of pass
 --------------------------------------------------
 FooProceso | 4                    | 2
```

Comment: Please don't post images for sample data instead include sample data in textual format or better to use any online tool([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)/[rextester.com](http://rextester.com)), Also include your complete table definitions and expected output

Comment: oh, ok, sorry. I will try. Idk how to format tables properly. I'll try.

Comment: Please include sample data and expected output in your question

Comment: Data sample and EO ready, i really appreciate your help

Comment: I guess Amount of pass should be 3 ? not 2

Comment: Nope, because the second record date for the same person is after the first, and is 0 (not pass). I need count of records which last interview of the applicant for the `proceso` in the `DPT` is 1

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help, finally I did it with:

```
SELECT p.id_proceso, p.proceso,
                               (
                                SELECT count(id_entrevista)                                                                 
                                from entrevista                                                                 
                                where entrevista.proceso = p.id_proceso                                                             
                               ) as q_entrevistas,                                                              
                             (
                                select count(distinct(ee.candidato))                                                                    
                                from entrevista ee                                                                  
                                where ee.proceso = p.id_proceso                                                                 
                                and ee.candidato not in (                                                                                                   
                                                          select e.candidato                                                                                                    
                                                          from entrevista e                                                                                                 
                                                          where e.proceso = p.id_proceso and e.resultado = 0
                                                        )
                            ) as aptos
FROM proceso p
WHERE p.dpt = $dpt //in this case i use PHP
```